# ignore regex in diff

Tags: bash, diff

I'm wondering if there's any clever ways to do a diff of two files, but to treat certain substrings as insignificant.   So for example, if I had two auto-generated files such as:

```
TIME:09:15:27
dir1/foo.c: val=1
dir1/bar.c: val=2
```

and

```
TIME:09:18:42
dir2/foo.c: val=1
dir2/bar.c: val=7
```

I'd like diff to ignore the strings `dir1` and `dir2`, and to ignore the `TIME:xx:xx:xx` line.   Thus, it should only pick out the difference between `dir2/bar.c: val=X` lines...

I can do something like this:

```
tmp> diff -U0 <(sed "s/dir[0-9]\+/DIR/g" file1.log) <(sed "s/dir[0-9]\+/DIR/g" file2.log) -I "TIME*"
--- /dev/fd/63  2020-06-17 10:24:43.966130403 -0400
+++ /dev/fd/62  2020-06-17 10:24:43.966130403 -0400
@@ -1,3 +1,3 @@
-DIR/bar.c: val=7
+DIR/bar.c: val=3
```

But, it has a few disadvantages: first, it's onerous to type, and second, it corrupts the dir1/dir2 strings in the output.   I'd like something like:

```
tmp> diff -U0 file1.log file2.log --ignore "\wdir[0-9]\w" --ignore "^TIME:.*"
-dir1/bar.c: val=7
+dir2/bar.c: val=3
```

I do this sort of thing often, so if anyone has any clever tricks, I'd love to hear them.

Comment: Reread your question: *I'd like diff to ignore the strings dir1 and dir2, and to ignore the TIME:xx:xx:xx line. Thus, it should only pick out the difference between dir2/bar.c: val=X lines...*.  You want to ignore dir2, and pick out the differenc between dir2...  You want to ignore it **and** pick it out?

Comment: I'm thinking you missed the point -- I want to ignore the difference between `dir1` and `dir2`, but not anything else.   Thus the second lines in the file `dir1/foo.c:val=1` and `dir2/foo.c:val=1` would be considered identical, but `dir1/bar.c:val=3` and `dir2/bar.c:val=7` would be different due to the `7` vs `3`.     This is paramount to ignoring whitespace changes except I want to ignore certain regex's instead of whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Regex with diff -I don't work very well.
You must have one same line in each file to get it to work.
sed, here, is not the good tool.
You can try with awk.

`awk -F '/' '
/^TIME|^$/{next}
{a[$NF]++;b[$NF]=$0}
END{for (i in a)if (a[i] == 1) {print b[i]}}' \
file1.log file2.log`

Field separator is set to /
first, remove the line with TIME
Array a and b are indexed with the last field (I think it is what you look for)
Array a keep the occurence of the last field.
Array b keep the entire line.
At the end, if a line come only one time, print it.

Comment: Thanks for this -- I was, however looking for something a bit more generic, that would specifically be able to ignore regex patterns.   I can write a script to do this, but I was hoping that some clever trick already existed...